# USB Mouse Freezing in Debian / KDE // Keyboard OK

Tags: debian, usb, mouse, freeze

Having problems with seemingly random freezes of my Logitech Wireless Mouse in Debian (KDE). With regards to a number of articles out there, I don't have powertop, mouseemu or laptop-mode-tools installed so can't do anything with them.

I'll be in the middle of using the mouse and the cursor freezes.  The keyboard is fine and using it on a Win8 laptop experiences no issues.  I need to unplug the mouse receiver and plug it back in to get it to work.

Any ideas how I can get this to stop working.

lsusb:

```
Bus 003 Device 058: ID 046d:c50e Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse Receiver
```

dmesg:

```
Jan  2 09:46:50 msc001 kernel: [1128796.493423] usb 3-8.2: USB disconnect, device number 58
Jan  2 09:46:52 msc001 kernel: [1128798.738982] usb 3-8.2: new low-speed USB device number 59 using xhci_hcd
Jan  2 09:46:52 msc001 kernel: [1128798.835914] usb 3-8.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c50e
Jan  2 09:46:52 msc001 kernel: [1128798.835918] usb 3-8.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan  2 09:46:52 msc001 kernel: [1128798.835920] usb 3-8.2: Product: USB RECEIVER
Jan  2 09:46:52 msc001 kernel: [1128798.835922] usb 3-8.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
Jan  2 09:46:52 msc001 kernel: [1128798.836118] usb 3-8.2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
Jan  2 09:46:52 msc001 kernel: [1128798.844939] input: Logitech USB RECEIVER as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-8/3-8.2/3-8.2:1.0/0003:046D:C50E.0084/input/input148
Jan  2 09:46:52 msc001 kernel: [1128798.845208] hid-generic 0003:046D:C50E.0084: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB RECEIVER] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8.2/input0
Jan  2 09:46:52 msc001 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 59: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-8/3-8.2"
Jan  2 09:46:52 msc001 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 59 was not an MTP device
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: No I did not, but I'm using a different mouse and I've not had any problems since changing to this one.  I did however with two prior to that (one wired, one wireless), so there is a problem, just can't fault find it.